# How did the Borg come into being?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, borg, star-trek-first-contact

Pretty straight forward question. How did the Borg start? Is there anything in the STU, or in novels, or anywhere that deals with the creation of the Borg, Borg Queen, first Drone, etc.? Was there an evolutionary process? Did V-Ger collide with some primordial ooze?

How did the Borg originate?

I'm using a capital 'B' in Borg as it's a proper noun like Missouri, not a common noun like elf,or human, huh?

Answer (score 0):

The shows give very little information on the Borg's origins.

Memory Alpha has this:

> The origin of the Borg is vague. What is known is by hearsay or brief
>   contacts with Borg survivors or even the Borg itself.
>
> According to the Borg Queen, the species known as the Borg started out
>   as normal lifeforms without any cybernetic enhancements thousands of
>   centuries ago. Over the years, they evolved into a mixture of organic
>   and artificial life. (Star Trek: First Contact; TNG: "Q Who") It is
>   believed that the Borg originated in the Delta Quadrant, where they
>   already existed in 1484. At that time, only a handful of star systems
>   had been assimilated by them and they had many encounters with a
>   species who called themselves the Vaadwaur. (VOY: "Dragon's Teeth")

There is more information from the novels as to their origins, but a lot of it is contradictory and it is not considered canon.

Go check out the [Memory Beta page](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Borg_history) on the non-canon origins of he Borg.